# Change Background at fixed interval of time

Tags: android, android-view, android-handler

I am trying to change the background of the activity at fixed interval of time.
This is the code of my activity

```
public class ExploreActivity extends Activity {

private int randNum = 0 ;
private int [] colorID = {R.color.AliceBlue,R.color.Beige,R.color.YellowGreen};
private Random rand = new Random();



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_explore);


     final Handler handler = new Handler(getMainLooper(), new Callback() {

        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(colorID[msg.arg1]);
            return true;
        }
    });

    final Message msg = new Message();


    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {


        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            randNum = rand.nextInt(colorID.length);
            msg.arg1 = randNum;
            handler.sendMessageAtFrontOfQueue(msg);



        }
    }, 5000, 5000);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.explore, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_logout:{
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("settings", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("login_state", false);
        editor.commit();
        finish();

    }
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }


}





 }
```

I am getting this error , the color change occurs only once then this error comes

```
 07-01 08:03:28.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3104): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 07-01 08:03:28.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3104): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The         specified message queue synchronization  barrier token has not been posted or has already been removed.
 07-01 08:03:28.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):    at android.os.MessageQueue.removeSyncBarrier(MessageQueue.java:266)
 07-01 08:03:28.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):    at android.os.Looper.removeSyncBarrier(Looper.java:242)
 07-01 08:03:28.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:981)
 07-01 08:03:28.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
 07-01 08:03:28.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
 07-01 08:03:28.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
 07-01 08:03:28.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
 07-01 08:03:28.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
 07-01 08:03:28.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
 07-01 08:03:28.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 07-01 08:03:28.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 07-01 08:03:28.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
 07-01 08:03:28.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 07-01 08:03:28.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 07-01 08:03:28.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
 07-01 08:03:28.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
 07-01 08:03:28.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Plz help me with the appropriate way of doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a solution from an example on developer.android.com

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler(getMainLooper(), new Callback() {

        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            root.setBackgroundResource(imageID[msg.arg1]);
            return true;
        }
    });




    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {


        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            randNum = rand.nextInt(imageID.length);
            Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(1, randNum, 0);
            msg.sendToTarget();
        }
    }, 5000, 8000);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily acheive what you are looking for using [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html). just create a list of your colors inside your AnimationDrawable xml file.
and in your onCreate method, attach the drawable to the background and start the animation when the screen gains focus.

example darwable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">
 <item android:drawable="@color/red" android:duration="600" />
 <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:duration="600" />

</animation-list>
```

and for the activity:

```
    AnimationDrawable drawable;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    View parent = findViewById(R.id.parent);
    drawable = (AnimationDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.animation_drawable);
    parent.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
}
 @Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean gained){
  super.onWindowFocusChanged(gained);
  if(gained){
    drawable.start();
}
}
```

Comment: how it can be random , i mean the sequence of colors

Comment: then re-size your drawables to a smaller size

Answer (score 0):

As being an activity and you want to change the color periodically, I suggest you to add an **id** to the Parent view of the layout and the use `findViewById(R.id.parentView)` instead of your `getWindow()`. I believe the error to be in that place.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the documents [[Link]](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#sendMessageAtFrontOfQueue%28android.os.Message%29)? About `sendMessageAtFrontOfQueue` :

*This method is only for use in very special circumstances -- it can easily starve the message queue, cause ordering problems, or have other unexpected side-effects.*

Can you check if `sendMessage` instead of `sendMessageAtFrontOfQueue` solves the issue?

Comment: i checked the sendMessage method but same error. I also tried msg.sendToTarget but again after first time same error

Comment: The stacktrace you posted, is the full one?